# Need help recursion explanation Leetcode

Tags: recursion, foreach, nested-loops

How does this code work? (leetcode 95 question) I don't understand how the 2 recursions work inside the for loop. Does the 2nd inner for loop end when the recursive function returns NULL? Or would it continue executing the 3rd inner for loop?

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<TreeNode*> generateTrees(int n) {
        
        
        if(n == 0) {
            return {};
        }
        
        vector<TreeNode*> ans = generateT(1,n);
        return ans;
        
        
    }
    
    
    vector<TreeNode*> generateT(int l, int r) {
        if(l > r) return {nullptr};
        vector<TreeNode*> ans;
        for(int i=l; i <= r; ++i) {
            for(TreeNode*left: generateT(l, i-1)) {
                for(TreeNode* right:generateT(i+1, r)) {
                    ans.push_back(new TreeNode(i));
                    ans.back()->left = left;
                    ans.back()->right = right;
                }
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

**Problem statement:**
Given an integer n, return all the structurally unique BST's (binary search trees), which has exactly n nodes of unique values from 1 to n. Return the answer in any order.

Comment: where do you see the recursive function returning NULL? I don't think it does so, ever. --- do you understand what `for(TreeNode*left: generateT(l, i-1)) { ... }` means?

Answer (score 0):

> Does the 2nd inner for loop end when the recursive function returns NULL?

No. The recursive function is not returing NULL, it is returning vector of nullptr.

> Or would it continue executing the 3rd inner for loop?

Of course, it will.

> How does this code work? I don't understand how the 2 recursions work inside the loop.

I suppose the following snippet is the cause of confusion, so commented the case when `nullptr` provided by outer loop.

```cpp
 vector<TreeNode*> generateT(int l, int r) {
        
        if(l > r) return { nullptr };
        vector<TreeNode*> ans;
        
        for ( int i = l; i <= r; i++ ) {
            // if l = 0, i = 0
            for ( TreeNode* left :generateT(l, i-1) ) // if l = 0, i = -1, returns { nullptr } (vector of nullptr)
                for (TreeNode* right :generateT(i+1, r)) { // now this snippet will execute
                    auto node = new TreeNode(i);
                    ans.push_back(node);
                    node->left = left;  // the nullptr we have from the outer loop, will provide null value for this
                    node->right = right;
                }
        }
            
        return ans;
    }
```

Visually, for a combination of node where,

```
  a
   \
    b
   / \
null  c
     /
    null
```

the above pattern occurs the provided `{ nullptr }` from outer loop will come in handy setting left node.